# Finding expected value of a prize

Tags: probability

> We roll a pair of dice 10 times in a row
>   If we get exactly $i$ rolls that none of them contained the number 4 (on both dice) we win $3^i$ dollars for $i=0,1,...,10$

What is the expected value of the prize?

Well I know that if we let x be the number of times we get no 4 in our rolls then:
$X$~$B(10, \frac{25}{36})$
So the expected value of X would be $np=10*\frac{25}{36}=6.944$

And if we let Y be the value of our prize then $Y=3^X$

but how can I calculate the expected value of Y now?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $X$ is discrete then $$E(u(X))=\sum_xu(x)P(X=x).$$ Please refer to "the law of the unconscious statistician", as it is sometimes called.

Comment: @Did We didn't learn that yet so I think there must be a simpler way

Comment: You are asked to find $E(3^X)$ but you did not learn how to compute expectations of functions of random variables, yet? Sorry but I doubt that.

Comment: @Did maybe I wasn't asked to find $E(3^X)$ it just what I got in my calculation it may be wrong, the only formula we have ever learnt about expected value is that $E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$ its not a full probability course it is a reduced one for B.Sc

Comment: The alternative (which is not difficult) is to compute directly $P(Y=y)$ for every $y$.